# Criteria - Eagerly fetch associated objects' properties

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-criteria

I have two entities joined by a join table. When I try to fetch all the associated entities, this only fetches the identity of the associations, not their property values:

```
User.createCriteria().get {
    eq property, value
    fetchMode 'authorities', FetchMode.JOIN
}
```

results only in a join with the join table:

```
...
left outer join
    search_role_auth_user authoritie2_ 
        on this_.ID=authoritie2_.AUTHORITIES_ID 
...
```

How can I eagerly fetch the the associated entity's data as well?

Comment: How does `User` and `Authority` domain class look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming,

```
class User{
    static hasMany = [authorities: Authority]
}

class Authority{
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

`authorities` can be eagerly fetched in criteria as below

```
User.createCriteria().list {
    eq property, value
    authorities{
       //All authorities for User are eagerly fetched by default
    }
}
```

**Note:-**
`list` is used instead of `get` because there is a possibility of getting more than one result as the criteria is built based on an `id` comparison but a property value.

Comment: Thanks, this works and is better than the HQL I ended up writing. By the way, is this explained somewhere? I don't see anything [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html). Also, this seems to create an alias (`criteria.createAlias` is called in `HibernateCriteriaBuilder::createAliasIfNeccessary`), but does it with `joinType = INNER_JOIN`, however, the resulting SQL has a left join. What's going on?

Comment: Ah, I misread the log. This is indeed an inner join, which doesn't work for me.

Comment: OK, solved with `createAlias('authorities', 'a', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)`

Comment: @Artefacto Have a look at [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#criteria). Also by default associations are fetched by inner join using criteria. If you explicitly want outer join (specifically left outer join) then you can follow [this](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2011/11/01/criteria-query-with-left-outer-join/).